# 3D model draggable within described range | R3F

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, three.js

I’m trying to restrict the drag area of my 3d models within the floor of my `FinalRoom.glb` model. I’ve converted it into tsx with `gltfjsx` and got this as output:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import { GLTF } from "three-stdlib";

type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {
    Cube_1: THREE.Mesh;
    Cube_2: THREE.Mesh;
  };
  materials: {
    ["Material.005"]: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
    ["Material.006"]: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
  };
};

export function FinalRoom(props: JSX.IntrinsicElements["group"] | any) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/models/finalRoom.glb") as GLTFResult;
  return (
    <group
      {...props}
      dispose={null}
      castShadow
      receiveShadow
      position={[0, -3, 0]}
    >
      <group
        position={[0, 0, 0]}
        scale={[
          (props.width * 1.68) / 4000,
          (props.height * 1.1) / 4000,
          (props.length * 1.68) / 4000,
        ]}
      >
        {/* FLOOR */}
        <mesh
          geometry={nodes.Cube_1.geometry}
          material={materials["Material.005"]}
          material-side={THREE.FrontSide}
          receiveShadow
          material-color={props.shiny ? "beige" : "#ffffff"}
          onPointerEnter={() => props.setShiny(true)}
          onPointerLeave={() => props.setShiny(false)}
        />
        {/* WALLS */}
        <mesh
          geometry={nodes.Cube_2.geometry}
          material={materials["Material.006"]}
          material-side={THREE.FrontSide}
          castShadow
          material-color={"#818181"}
        />
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/models/finalRoom.glb");
```

Now can anyone please tell me how can I make other models come only on floor when I import them and make them stay within the floor area. and yeah the floor area is dynamic user can change it as per their requirement. if it was static it was not this complicated for me but I’m not even getting how to make other models draggable just draggable and after that restricting the area is too much complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the explicit return type for the getStaticProps() function in the case of typescript.

this will fix the issue for you

```
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
export async function getStaticProps(): GetStaticProps<{ state: boolean }> {
  return {
    props: {
      state: true
    }
  }
}
```